# Triangle Inequality for quotients

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials

Problem states the $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ are complex polynomials with $deg(p)=m$ and  $deg(q)=n$. I need to show that

$\mid \frac {p(z)}{q(z)}\mid \leq R^{m-n}C$

when $\mid z \mid$ = $R$

I am tempted to use the triangle inequality to get the individual powers of $R$ but I am not sure if it will work because of the denominator

if $\mid a + b\mid \leq \mid a \mid + \mid b \mid$ then the inequality is reversed for the quotient

Comment: Maybe the argument principle?

Comment: Could you elaborate?